# How to run .remove() after fade-out effect is completed?

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to run the line "this.parentElement.remove();" after the line "this.parentElement.classList.add("fade-out");" is completed (fade-out lasts 1 second).

Right now .remove() runs instantly so the fade-out effect does not show.

Many thanks in advance!

```
var deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
  deleteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    this.parentElement.classList.add("fade-out");
    this.parentElement.remove();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

Comment: I recommend adding a [mcve]. What's `fade-out`'s CSS, for example and what does the markup look like? You can create a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Thanks for clarifying and welcome to SO.

Comment: Take a look at [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the duration of your fade inside timeout function and when it's done the callback function will execute

**Code sample**

```js
const deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll("span");

const FADE_OUT_TIME = 2000;
for (let i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
  deleteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.classList.add("fade-out");
    setTimeout(_ => this.remove(), FADE_OUT_TIME)
  });
}
```

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="cursor-pointer">first</span>
<span class="cursor-pointer">second</span>
<span class="cursor-pointer">third</span>
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene Sunic, this worked perfectly!

Do you know by any chance if it is possible to get the same result without setTimeout so I won't have to hard code the fade out duration?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to listen in on the event's `transitionend` event ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event)).

```
let el = this.parentElement;
el.addEventListener('transitionend', () => el.remove());
el.classList.add("fade-out");
```

The attractiveness of this approach versus listening for a timeout means you don't have to hard-code the transition duration in your JavaScript (if you ever change it, you'd have to update both your CSS and your JavaScript.) The event will fire whenever it ends, however long it takes.

Comment: Thank you Utkanos, I was hoping to get a solution without a timeout for exactly that reason, only this code did not work for me. The solution of Eugene Sunic does work, but as you mentioned, I have to hard-code the transition duration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.fade-out` triggers an animation, you can add a `animationend` to the element to achieve this... The callback is called after any animation has ended

```
var deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
    deleteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        this.parentElement.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
            this.parentElement.remove();
        });

        this.parentElement.classList.add("fade-out");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kwame, but unfortunately the code does not work with the error code "deleteItem[i].event is not a function".

Comment: Sorry....it was supposed to be `addEventListener` not `event`...

Comment: Thank you Kwame, the issue I have here is that only the fade out animation runs, but the item is not actually deleted afterwards.